# Check if item is in list of list

Tags: python

I'm looking to see if item is in list of list.

```
List1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

If `b` is in any of the list in a list, then print `True`. Else, print `False`.

What's the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
# check element exists in list of list or not? 
result = any("b" in sublist for sublist in List1) 

# printing result 
print(str(result))
```

Comment: Um... what's the point of `str(...)` here?

Comment: @superbrain Oh, I dunno.  There’s at least as much a point as your nit-picking something really minor that really isn’t part of the answer but secondary to it.

Comment: @JLPeyret I don't see how none is at least as much as some.

Comment: Whatever. And I find your answer harder to grok too but I suppose you just had to make it look better by nit picking someone else’s.

Answer (score 0):

I'll play the fool...

```
>>> 'b' in sum(List1, [])
True
>>> 'B' in sum(List1, [])
False
```